# Cucumber Background and persisting Scenarios (or prerequisites)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, cucumber

I had this problem [Cucumber scenarios for extremely long work flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4902361/cucumber-scenarios-for-extremely-long-work-flow)

And now I've been writing isolated scenarios for each of a long series of multi-part form steps. I have a `Background` section that sets up each `Scenario`. But now when I run the entire feature, cucumber wants to repeat the `Background` for each `Scenario`. I want to test a `Scenario` that builds off of all the previous ones.

Here is the bare outline of what my feature looks like:

```
Feature: Submit a manuscript
  In order to complete a manuscript submission
  As a corresponding author
  I want to complete the to-do list

  Background:
    Given I am logged in as "Steve"
    And an article_submission "Testing Web Apps" exists
    And "Steve" is a "Corresponding Author" for "Testing Web Apps"
    And I am on the manuscript to-do list page for "Testing Web Apps"

  Scenario: Steve suggests reviewers for his manuscript
    ...
  Scenario: Steve completes the manuscript fees to-do item
    ...
  Scenario: Steve wants to add Barbara as a co-author
    ...
  Scenario: Steve uploads necessary files
    ...
  Scenario: Steve edits the fees page and general information page
    ...
  Scenario: Steve re-uploads the manuscript file
    ...
  Scenario: Steve completes the Copyright Transfer
    ...
  Scenario: Steve completes Author Responsibilities & Agreement
    ...
  # These scenarios depend on all the previous ones having run  
  Scenario: Steve Completes submission
    ...
  Scenario: Steve goes back and make changes
    ...
  Scenario: Steve fills out payment page
```

Is there are way to require previous scenarios to be run? And is there a way of running the `Background` only once?

Comment: I think you might be making things harder on yourself than they need to be. What you have listed as scenarios read to me like steps in a scenario instead. Like Pan mentioned on the answer to the question you link to, your scenarios should be self-contained and not have dependencies between them like this. If it were me, I'd collapse the background and scenarios back into a small handful (the 3 on the end would probably each become 1 scenario) and use higher level steps like "Given Steve has completed the manuscript submission" and have verifications in those to make sure each step worked.

Comment: These scenarios are, for the most part, self-contained. Believe me, these scenarios are not short. I already have hundreds of steps. Combining them makes it harder to read and less self-contained. I have refactored wherever I could to move commonly-used steps into step definition files. What I think I really need is a way to freeze the database after a feature runs and then load it up before the next dependent feature.

Comment: The way our application works is there is a long workflow for an author, then another for a reviewer, and another for the revision process. Each workflow depends on the conditions set up by the previous one. I've already got lots of fixtures and factories loading up data but what I need is a factory that creates all the models at once. I don't want to repeat Feature A and B everytime I need to test Feature C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I decided to "freeze" the application in the state it was immediately after running the Feature. I did this by adding hooks that dump and load the databse.

In `features/support/hooks.rb` I have:

```
After('@complete-submission') do
  # Dump the database
  exec "mysqldump -u root --password=### onc_test > #{Rails.root}/support/submission.sql"
end

Before('@load-submission') do
  # Load the database
  exec "mysql -u root --password=### onc_test < #{Rails.root}/support/submission.sql"
end
```

This is working basically, except the `@load-submission` fails mysteriously to run the Scenario, but the database is loaded. So I have to run it again without the tag. Maybe someone can help me figure that own out.